# Yodlee addSiteAccount1 Error : code 403 and 522

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying without success since few days to use my Yodlee REST API with CIBC Bank(Site Id = 10457). but I'm getting refresh code = 522 and while running getMFAResponseForSite. i get code 403.

```
"siteRefreshStatus":{"siteRefreshStatusId":0,"siteRefreshStatus":"REFRESH_TRIGGERED"},"siteRefreshMode":{"refreshModeId":1,"refreshMode":"MFA"},"updateInitTime":0,"nextUpdate":1402776432,"code":522,"noOfRetry":0}

{"siteRefreshStatus":{"siteRefreshStatusId":8,"siteRefreshStatus":"REFRESH_COMPLETED_WITH_UNCERTAIN_ACCOUNT"},"siteRefreshMode":{"refreshModeId":1,"refreshMode":"MFA"},"updateInitTime":0,"nextUpdate":1403044246,"code":403,"noOfRetry":0}
```

522 :"MFA error: Request Timed Out (522) :Your request has timed out as the required security information was unavailable or was not provided within the expected time. Please try again."

403 : "Problem Updating Account(403):We're sorry, there was a technical problem updating your account. This kind of error is usually resolved in a few days. Please try again later.".

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already a customer then please use Yodlee Customer Care tool for raising a Service Request else you can please fill out the form mentioned [here](http://solutions.yodlee.com/APIDeveloperInquiryForm.html) to provide the details like siteAccountId & REST URL you are using for us to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the refresh status of this site and it looks good. Usually, you get 522 because the application was expecting an answer from the user and it timed out because user did not provide the same. The 403s are issues that Yodlee needs to fix. You can find more details on the developer portal [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes).

If you think you are still not able to get a resolution, you can raise a service request and we will take care of it.